# Stability of discrete time systems.

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, optimal-control

Let a discrete time system be
\begin{align}
x[k+1]=Ax[k]
\end{align}
If the system in Eq.1 is stable then always it will satisfy the Lyapunov equation as described below.

Let the Lyapunov function be $V[k]=x[k]^TPx[k]$, for a positive definite $P$. So, $\nabla V= V[k+1]-V[k]$ should be $<0$. This gives
\begin{align}
\nabla V= &V[k+1]-V[k]\\
= &x[k+1]^TPx[k+1]  - Vx[k]^TPx[k]\\
= & x^T[k] (A^TPA-P)   x^T[k] 
\end{align}
So we can conclude $(A^TPA-P)<0$.

But in some places it is written as $(APA^T-P)<0$. WHY?? and HOW they are same.

Comment: Do you have a source where it is written that way? Maybe there they are using the conversion of using a row vector instead of a column vector (and thus $x[k+1]=x[k]\,A$ and $V(x[k])=x[k]\,P\,x^\top[k]$).

Comment: Eigenvalues are invariant by transposition. So, those LMIs are equivalent.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen For example the Matlab function [dlyap](https://de.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dlyap.html), at least the equation there is called "discrete-time Lyapunov equation". This is quite annoying because you always have to remember to call the function like `P=dlyap(A',Q)` instead of just `P=dlyap(A,Q)`, which would be much more intuitive but will give you the "wrong" solution. Would be interesting to know why they chose to do it this way.

Comment: Maybe this conventions is coming from the way it can be solved numerically. For example $A\,P\,A^\top-P=-Q$ can also be written as $(A \otimes A - I \otimes I)\,\text{vec}(P)=-\text{vec}(Q)$ (with $\otimes$ the Kronecker product and $\text{vec}$ the vectorization operator, see [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)). So the equivalent equations for $A^\top P\,A-P=-Q$ would be $(A^\top \otimes A^\top - I \otimes I)\,\text{vec}(P)=-\text{vec}(Q)$, which requires taking the transpose of $A$ while the previous expression didn't.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Maybe, but you could just change the order of the relevant for-loop to get the same result without actually transposing the matrix. But it is what it is.

Comment: @SampleTime it remains strange why dlyap() is the way it is. Namely, I checked the references on that page that mention Lyapunov equation (reference 1, 3 and 5; the other references look like to be about other/more general topics) and they all use the more logical convention of $A^\top P\,A-P=-Q$. So someone at Matlab has made a conscious decision to do it the other way.